# Can't get Chrome extension to run its PHP file via XML request

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a Chrome extension that simply parses out some data from a certain webpage's markup and then sends that data over to a PHP file that is also part of my extension. While I get no errors from my Javascript, it seems to me that the PHP file is not in fact being executed, and I can't even figure out how to debug.

Based on review of many tutorials and SO searches, my approach is to have my Javascript file send an XML request to a PHP file, which will talk with my MySQL database (hosted through freesqldatabase.com)

My file structure for unpacked loading is:

- my_php_file.php
- content.js
- jquery-3.6.0.min.js
- manifest.json

My manifest looks like this (some values redacted for clarity):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "my extension name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.thesiteImworkingon.com/games/play.phtml*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["my_php_file.php"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js looks like this (again, some variable names modified for clarity):

```
// a bunch of querySelector statements to parse out my data of interest; save these as var1 etc.

var query = chrome.runtime.getURL("my_php_file.php") + "?par1=" + var1 + "&par2=" + var2 + "&par3=" + var3 + "&par4=" + var4;
console.log(query); // looks as expected

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onerror = function() {console.log('error');};
xhr.open("GET", query, true);
xhr.send();
```

my_php_file.php looks like this (again, redacted/modified for clarity):

```
<?php

echo "I'm in the PHP file";


$var1 = $_GET['par1'];
$var2 = $_GET['par2'];
$var3 = $_GET['par3'];
$var4 = $_GET['par4'];

$con = mysqli_connect('[host name]',
                      '[user name]',
                      '[password]',
                      '[db name]',
                      db port);
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES(".$var1 .",".$var2.",".$var3.",".$var4.")";

mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I open the relevant page in my browser, the parsing part of the Javascript file works perfectly (logs to console confirm this), and I even get successful result (XML request's readyState is 4 and status is 200), but my `echo` doesn't seem to show up anywhere and my database table remains empty. I'd try debugging the PHP somehow but it seems like it's not actually being executed?

Is it not ok to have my PHP script be part of my extension? Do I need to host it on a proper server (even if just `localhost`)?

This is my first time developing a Chrome extension (and coding Javascript and PHP, for that matter) and I worry that I have made some error so fundamental that I'm not able to find its resolution despite my searches

Comment: you are probably running another file

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia How might I be doing that? Isn't my getURL call quite clear to the interpreter?

Comment: if you go to that address in your browser (put the URL in the search bar) what does appear?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia It shows the raw text of the code of my PHP file if I view it with my normal browser. (If I use incognito browser, I get `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`)

Comment: therefore you are not running a web server

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I'm not positive I see the implication here. Is it that it is not enough to simply include the PHP file with my unpacked load? I.e., the answer to my final question ("Do I need to host it on a proper server (even if just `localhost`)?") is yes?

Comment: Yes, PHP is a server side language and you need a server to interpreter your PHP code. Your browser can't run PHP code.